Using ox-pandoc with ox-extra ignore headlines removes footnotes when using pandoc export
I am using the ignore-headlines feature that is part of ox-extra that comes with org-contrib. I enable that feature this way:
  (use-package org-contrib
    :config
    (require 'ox-extra)
    (ox-extras-activate '(ignore-headlines)))


Then I use it like this:
#+TITLE: Some document
* Header 1 :ignore:
  ... content with org-style footnotes ...
* Footnotes
  ... footnotes ...

When I do this, however, the footnotes do not appear in my pandoc export. If I export, with the standard markdown backend that comes with emacs, I do see the footnotes.
Has anyone else run into this? Does anyone know if there is a way around it?
